# How to get a contact list from a gmail account within Yii framework 2.0

Tags: php, list, gmail, yii2, contacts

I already have created a Google app. I want to get a contact list from a gmail account for my Yii 2.0 website. I saw two interesting classes that Yii 2.0 provides:

```
 yii\authclient\clients\GoogleOAuth
 yii\authclient\clients\GoogleOpenId
```

Can I use the above classes to get a contact list from a gmail account? If yes, how do I implement it, because in Yii 2.0 docs there is not sample code for using these classes. If no, does any one know a good tutorial to approach this goal? I am working with Yii framework 2.0

Comment: There are two possible scenarios: either you do it for one user only (yourself), in which case you can store the token in your yii2 code, or you do it for any user, in which case the user will be taken to a google page asking him to confirm the operation, then redirected back to your yii2 site. Which is the one you need?